# How do I multiply a numpy array by a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `T`:

```
[ 0.2  0.4  0.4]
[ 0.8  0.2  0. ]
[ 0.8  0.   0.2]

T = numpy.mat("0.2 0.4 0.4;0.8 0.2 0.0;0.8 0.0 0.2")
```

I have vector `v`, numpy.array(73543, -36772, 36772)

```
v = numpy.array([ 73543, -36772, 36772])
```

How do I multiply the array `v` by the matrix `T` correctly in python?

thanks,

Chris

Comment: to clarify, do you want to perform v*T or T*v?

Answer (score 1):

use `numpy.dot`, which is not quite same as `*` operator:

```
In [138]: T.dot(v) #the resulting shape is (1, 3), not (3, 1) if you don't care
Out[138]: matrix([[ 14708.6,  51480. ,  66188.8]])

In [139]: v.dot(T) #same with v * T
Out[139]: matrix([[ 14708.6,  22062.8,  36771.6]])

In [140]: T.dot(v[:, None]) #if you need the shape to be (3, 1) when doing T*v
Out[140]: 
matrix([[ 14708.6],
        [ 51480. ],
        [ 66188.8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
v * T
```

numpy overload arithmetic operates in ways that make sense most of the time. In your case, since T is a matrix, it converts v to a matrix as well before doing the multiplication. That turns v into a row-vector. Therefore `v*T` performs matrix multiplication, but `T*v` throws an exception because v is the wrong shape. However you can make v the correct shape with `v.reshape(3,1)` or treat v as a vector of the correct orientation with `T.dot(v)` or `numpy.dot(T,v)`.